# When can we describe people as "intact"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-person-remains-intact.2718575/):

> **(1)** *In a terrible car accident, the driver not only survived, but also remained intact*. – We wouldn't use "intact" here because it sounds like his body didn't lose any pieces, i.e. his arms and legs aren't scattered along the road. We should use "unharmed" or "uninjured" here.

From the text above, I infer that we usually don't apply "*intact*" to people.
But I found (2) and (3):

"Extra Examples" from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/intact):
**(2)** *a hero who always escaped by the skin of his teeth, emerging miraculously **intact** after each cliff-hanging episode*
What does "intact" in (2) mean?
In (1), the usage of "intact" was wrong. But how is the meaning of "intact" in (2) different from its meaning in (1)?

[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/intact):
**(3)** *After a long day at work, you might feel lucky to be **intact***.
What does "intact" in (3) mean?

P.S.: I also saw one of the meanings of "intact" is "virginal" but I think it's better to leave it outside this question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd leave out discussion of the meanings of "intact" to refer to virginity or (absence of) castration - those are two important reasons that one might avoid using the word in contexts that it could be used otherwise.

Comment: ***Intact*** is often used highly figuratively in such contexts (it doesn't necessarily imply "without losing any limbs or other major body parts"). Compare *You'll* [*be lucky to get out **in one piece***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22be+lucky+to+get+out+in+one+piece%22) *[if you enter that dangerous place]*. Quite possibly the speaker knows perfectly well that the *worst* that could happen is you might get punched or otherwise injured - even if there's no possibility whatsoever that you might lose "parts", the idiom may still be used in such contexts.

Comment: Also, if there is psychological trauma, can the driver really be said to be "intact"?

Comment: Organs of the human body, such as the lungs or a leg, are often “intact.” Inanimate objects are very often “intact.” The word is rarely used of people.

Comment: "intact" is sometimes used to mean "uncircumcized"

Comment: @JoelFan You are correct, I was just going to say that.

Comment: 'Unscathed' or 'uninjured' are more likely phrases to use in British English in this context.

Comment: @Davislor - that was my first thought as well (actually, upon seeing the title of the question, my first thought was "when they're dead" - that is, we don't usually apply the word to people, but we do apply it to bodies.  However, the OP includes at least one example where it is actually applied to a live person (#2 - I find #3 does not sound right to me at all.)

Answer (score 12):

I would say that "intact" for a person does not have a very specific meaning, and is often used somewhat humorously (as in example 3) or dramatically (as in example 2). For that reason, it's best to avoid in serious writing.

I would agree with the advice in example 1.

Comment: Yes - I would agree with Wordreference that 'intact' reads oddly in the first example because the sentence is meant seriously, while (2) and (3) are 'tongue-in-cheek'.

Comment: It may be helpful for the OP to look up the idiom 'in one piece' because intact is often used in a similar way (for humour/dramatic effect as you describe) and they have similar meanings.

Answer (score 8):

"Intact" in both of the first two example sentences means "left whole or undamaged with respect to form or function--untouched". The word "intact" comes from the prefix "in-", meaning "not", and the Latin "tactus", meaning "touch". You see the original meaning of this word well preserved in the examples submitted in the question.

It means the same thing in the third example, though this example is somewhat figurative. Here, the thing that is described as "intact" is less the physical form of a person and more their emotional or mental state, and you may consider the usage figurative because emotional state can't literally be touched. An intact emotional or mental state, then, is one which has not suffered substantial damage such as, for example, a stress-induced breakdown or high anxiety.

The source you referenced in example 1 is incorrect. There is nothing wrong with using "intact" to mean "mostly undamaged", even when describing a person. However there is an important distinction to be made between "intact" and "undamaged", which is that damage of a low severity or superficial kind may indeed apply to something described as "intact". A thing may be described as "intact" if the amount of damage done to it is small enough that it does not substantially change the thing, either in form or function. So a person cut across their face such that will leave a scar may be described as intact, while a person impaled through the heart could not be described as intact.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You wrote _"intact" in both sentences means "left whole or undamaged with respect to form or function--untouched"_. Based on this phrase, I couldn't understand what meaning "intact" has in (3) and, therefore, what (3) means.

Comment: @Loviii - (3) seems to be discussing being mentally undamaged.

Comment: Yes, #3 is probably just a form of exaggeration, a figurative use of intact to mean "not broken emotionally".

Comment: @Lovii The meaning is the same in the third example, but I updated the answer to explain in greater detail.

Comment: You could also use the word "unscathed"- it has exactly the same meaning in both (1) and (2) without being weird when applied to people. In (3) it's not _quite_ as applicable but very subtly so- 'unscathed' is more firmly applicable to physical than mental state. It also seems just a bit off in present tense.

Comment: @Scott I don't believe it's odd to use "intact" to describe a person